# Wordpress set taxonomy on post?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

hello this is my code to select taxonomy for post by post id.

this is my code and this code is doesn't work please help.

```
wp_set_post_terms( '2653', array('Bus'), 'category_type_bus');
```

this is my code when i run that code.and then after checked in backend. the Bus is not selected please tell where i am wrong.

thank you.

Comment: what is the type of the taxonomy `category_type_bus`? Hierarchical or non hierarchical?

Comment: taxonomy type is Hierarchical.

Answer (score 2):

[`wp_set_post_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms) requires you to provide term id not the term name or slug *when it is a hierarchical taxonomy*.

**From the codex:**

> For hierarchical terms (such as categories), you must always pass the
>   id rather than the term name to avoid confusion where there may be
>   another child with the same name.

**Try the code below:**

```
$term_id = term_exists( 'bus', 'category_type_bus' ); 
wp_set_post_terms( '2653', array( $term_id ), 'category_type_bus' );
```

The function [`get_term_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) also can be used instead of [`term_exists()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists)

Hope it helps.